# Getting " Failed to create session. Request timed out" in Appium Inspector for iOS testing

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-java

I tried inspecting my iOS app on appium inspector, my WebDriver agent is also building successfully on xcode .

My Xcode version is 13.4.1

iOS =15.5

device = iPhone 13 Pro

Java Code:

```
    
                XCUITestOptions options = new XCUITestOptions();
                options.setDeviceName("iPhone 13 Pro");
                options.setApp("/Users/rishabhsingh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UIKitCatalog-cvawlrsplrgisaelokzxvyayuflr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UIKitCatalog.app");
                options.setPlatformVersion("15.5");
                //Appium -> Webdriver agent-> iOS apps
                options.setWdaLaunchTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
                
                
                 driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), options);
                 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

[image]